# Why is preg_match matching empty string when testing the following regex pattern?

Tags: php, regex, command

I formed a `regex` pattern to match strings representing commands in the following format:

```
!<name of command>\s+<possible parameters separated with commas>
```

or

```
!<name of command>
```

The `regex` looks like this a the moment:

```
^!(\w+)\s+([\w,\s]+\w+)$|^!(\w+)$
```

---

When I use `preg_match` to test an eventual string against my pattern:

```
$res = "!add"
preg_match('~^!(\w+)\s+([\w,\s]+\w+)$|^!(\w+)$~',$res,$match);
```

the `$match` array returned has 4 unexpected entries.

```
array(4) {
[0]=>
string(11) "!addhhgnhgj"
[1]=>
string(0) ""
[2]=>
string(0) ""
[3]=>
string(10) "addhhgnhgj"
}
```

Two strangely match empty string and the other two match the full string and the third capture group (as I was expecting). When `$res` equals to `"!add param1, param2"`, `$match` has exactly 3 entries as expected.

Why is the above happening when testing the string of a command followed by no parameters?

Comment: On regex101.com no empty string are matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Numbers are relative to capturing groups.

Your input string matches with second side of alternation `^!(\w+)$`. It stores whole match at index `0` of output array and `1` and `2` indexes correspond to capturing groups of first side of alternation that are not captured and third contains something that is at index `3`.

That is the reason for having `1` and `2` indexes empty.

```
^!(\w+)\s+([\w,\s]+\w+)$|^!(\w+)$
  --#1-   -----#2------    --#3-
```

Comment: Thanks now that makes more sense. I thought that what is not matched is automatically omitted.

Comment: If uninterested in the uncaptured CGs, simply use: `foreach (array_keys($match, '') as $key) unset($match[$key]);` after `preg_match`.

Comment: You don't output directly `$match` somewhere. You really don't need to do this. However there is a better way `array_filter($match);` @MarcoDufal

Comment: I use `$match` later one in my code but thanks for the heads up, `array_filter()` is better!

Comment: @MarcoDufal: you can also rewrite your pattern like this: `^!(\w+)(?:\s+([\w,\s]+\w))?$` *(when the last defined capture groups don't match, they don't appear in the result array.)*

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte sure I'll have a look. Do you mind explaining the semantics of `?:` ?

Comment: @MarcoDufal: `(?:...)` is only a non-capturing group.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte if I allow more special characters in addition to the comma, how can I stop their repetition in the captured string to occur (e.g. ",,,,,,,,,,") ?

Comment: @MarcoDufal: try to replace `[\w,\s]+\w` with `\w+(?:[\s,]\w+)*`